# Redirect external ip to localhost

Tags: ubuntu, networking, iptables

I have a ubuntu box behind NAT, with a static ip, and I want to redirect any connections coming from my 10.0.0.123 machine to my public ip to redirect back to localhost (my 10.0.0.123 machine).

How can I set up packet routing, so that all traffic from localhost to my external ip is routed back to localhost? (transparent for any application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My iptables is a little rusty, so I'm not 100% sure this will work. You could try this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -p tcp -d <public ip> -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Thx !! You save my day :)